# Application integration scenario for messaging system?

Tags: .net, integration, message-queue

I have a scenario where there is a backend system and a frontend system with a .NET based middleware in between. The backend system provides a REST API which is used by the frontend system.

The communication is always started with a POST request. This creates a session on the backend system. All subsequent requests contain the SessionId.
Many clients interact and all get their own session on this system.
The backend system can handle the different sessions in parallel, e.g. by returning information via an HTTP GET API.

However, there is a restriction: per session, both read and write requests can only be processed sequentially by the backend system.

The following screenshot illustrates this:

[image]

This restriction complicates the frontend because it actually wants to send parallel requests to the backend system. To keep the frontend
simple, I want to decouple .NET middleware layer and backend by a messaging system.

There are well known patterns like Competing Consumer and so on. Unfortunately I have not found a suitable standard pattern for my scenario.
Does anyone know an appropriate way to create this? If possible RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ/Artemis would be a possibility.

The scenario must work on premise and must not rely on specific cloud technologies. Also the solution should not decrease the overall system performance.

In my understanding, I would need a dynamically created message queue per SessionId (from the backend). All Requests on that session would need to be stored in this specific queue and being processed in sequence. As a result, there would exist as many queues as sessions on the backend. The following picture illustrates the basic idea with request and response queues for the two sessions A and B:

[image]

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: This question should be closed for a few different reasons. First, it's not a programming question, but rather more of a design/architecture question. Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Second, it's going to elicit opinion-based answers rather than fact-based answers. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: I dont agreed with you. I would bei rather interested also in Code Samples. But to get there, sind discussion is needed in the way.

Comment: As you note, before you can get to any code you need an answer to this design/architecture question which is going to elicit discussion and opinion-based answers. Questions like this deal with weighing various trade-offs for your specific use-case. There's no "correct" answer, strictly speaking. This not a coding question which can be answered clearly and factually. The fact that you've already had 3, very different answers and 7 additional comments is evidence to this fact. For all these reasons this question is off-topic. Check the links in my previous comment for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to wait for a response before sending further messages. But this might be degrading performance.

Another option is to package several messages into one bigger message. This [message aggregation](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html) would guarantee the order. It can be done on the client side or on the server side.

An ["exactly once in order" policy (EOIO)](https://www.integration-excellence.com/messaging-principles/) comes with a performance penalty. It might help to write a strictly increasing track ID in every message. This would allow the server to detect out-of-order messages. It depends on the overall requirements, how long the server should wait for delayed messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Waiting for the response is no option in our case because then we would have to implement specific logic on the client side. This would decrease performance as you mentioned.

Aggregation is also no option because we have a more or less endless series of requests - so we don't come to a point where we can aggregate in a goof way.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout ActiveMQ's support for wild-card consumers, auto-queue creation and auto-queue clean-up (aka garbage collection).

1. Create a queue-per-sesssion (queue://session.abcd, queue://session.xyz, etc)
2. Create a consumer queue://session.* (wild card matches all the dynamic queues)
3. Configure destination policy to automatically delete queues when they are no longer needed.

ref: https://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations

Comment: Thank you! That sounds quite interesting! Can I combine the wildcard consumers with a given response queue, perhaps in a way that every message hast ist own response queue and the message producer can define the response queue name? I think I would need such a scenario If I want to imitate a similar thing as requests/reply.

Comment: Yep.  JMS has a replyTo header defined as part of the specification. Producer can define the response queue, then the consumer reads it off the header of the message to produce the result. With 'GC' queues, you don't need to use TempQueue-- which aren't great for observability.

Comment: OK and is it possible to have more workers which listen to the queues but take in care that a message may only be taken out if the previously message has being processed?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution for my problem. It comes in form of a distributed Lock. There is a framework which can easily be used: https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock

Comment: you can also use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/zk-distributed-lock 
this package creates a distributed lock system and is easy to use with logging support also